# Why do I get this error when comparing two Numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

See the below error message. It points to this code which takes two numpy arrays with company brands and see if there are any new brand names in the `new_df` brand column.

I have looked at the input variables `new_df['brand'].unique(),existing_df['brand'].unique()` and neither of them are None, they are numpy arrays, so I don't get what the problem is:

```
#find new brands 
brand_diff = np.setdiff1d(new_df['brand'].unique(),existing_df['brand'].unique(),False)
count_brand_diff = len(brand_diff)
```

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-254b4c01e085> in <module>
     71 
     72         #find new brands
---> 73         brand_diff = np.setdiff1d(new_df['brand'].unique(),existing_df['brand'].unique(),False)
     74         count_brand_diff = len(brand_diff)
     75 

<__array_function__ internals> in setdiff1d(*args, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in setdiff1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique)
    782         ar1 = np.asarray(ar1).ravel()
    783     else:
--> 784         ar1 = unique(ar1)
    785         ar2 = unique(ar2)
    786     return ar1[in1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=True, invert=True)]

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    260     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    261     if axis is None:
--> 262         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    263         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    264 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    308         aux = ar[perm]
    309     else:
--> 310         ar.sort()
    311         aux = ar
    312     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NavigableString'```
````

Comment: You should provide a ready to use example, in that case a data sample is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the data you are using because the code is correct,

example:

```
>>existing_df
   brand
   apple
   apple 
   bmw

>>new_df
   brand
   apple
   lexus 
   bmw

>>count_brand_diff
    1
```

Hence, of you need more help, please provide an example of the data you are using.

Comment: Correct! A None value had snuck into the array. Hadn't done the proper cleaning. Thanks